# Distinguish between 'character' and 'numeric' data types in Python

Tags: python

I'm wondering if there is an easy way to distinguish character and numeric data types in Python (e.g. int/double/float etc.). Ideally, I'd like to be able to distinguish scalars as well as lists.

In short, I'd like to be able to write a function `easy_type` that will do the following:

```
>>> easy_type(["hello", "world"])  
   "character"
>>> easy_type("hello")  
   "character"
>>> easy_type(['1.0', '0.0'])  
   "numeric"
>>> easy_type([0, 1, 2])  
   "numeric"
>>> easy_type(0.100)  
   "numeric"
```

Comment: What would be the result of `["hello","1.0"] `?

Comment: @thefourtheye Ahh good point. It shouldn't happen in practice, but for completeness it should return `"multiple"`

Comment: What about an empty list?

Comment: There are a few applications where treating `'1.0'` as numeric is a good idea, but usually, it'll just lead to horrible problems. Make sure this is a good idea before you do it.

Comment: @user2357112 Good point. I think that this is what you were refering to? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29068483/python-sets-automatically-simplify-float-to-int

Comment: I was thinking of things like `'1' == 1`, `1 == '1.0'` `'1.0' != '1'` in Javascript or bugs you get in one language (I think it was PHP) where if you aren't careful, you'll get comparison results like `"1e2" == "100"` because the language is converting the strings to numbers for the comparison.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have multiple types of data, you might want to get the type of individual items with a recursive function, like this

```
def get_type(data):
    if isinstance(data, list):
        types = {get_type(item) for item in data}
        # If all elements of the list are of the same type
        if len(types) == 1:
            return next(iter(types))
        # if not, return "multiple"
        else:
            return "multiple"
    elif isinstance(data, str):
        # Check if the string has only numbers or it is a float number
        return "numeric" if data.isdigit() or is_float(data) else "character"
    elif isinstance(data, int) or isinstance(data, float):
        return "numeric"
```

And the helper function `is_float` is defined like this

```
def is_float(data):
    try:
        float(data)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False
```

And the tests,

```
assert(get_type(["hello", "world"]) == "character")
assert(get_type("hello") == "character")
assert(get_type(['1.0', '0.0']) == "numeric")
assert(get_type([0, 1, 2]) == "numeric")
assert(get_type(0.100) == "numeric")
```

Answer (score 1):

To handle `"character"` and `"numeric"` for scalars:

```
def easy_type(ob):
    try:
        float(ob)
        return "numeric"
    except ValueError:
        return "character"
```

To handle lists similarly, assuming all elements of a list are of the same type, and lists aren't nested and aren't empty:

```
def easy_type(ob):
    if isinstance(ob, list):
        return mytype(ob[0])
    try:
        float(ob)
        return "numeric"
    except ValueError:
        return "character"
```

To also handle `"multiple"`:

```
def easy_type(ob):
    if isinstance(ob, list):
        types = set((mytype(o) for o in ob))
        if len(types) > 1:
            return "multiple"
        else:
            return types.pop()
    try:
        float(ob)
        return "numeric"
    except ValueError:
        return "character"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can probably get most of what you want using the [built-in `type()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#type):

```
>>> type("hello").__name__
'str'
>>> type(1).__name__
'int'
>>> type(1.5).__name__
'float'
>>> type(["hello", "world"]).__name__
'list'
```

You will need to decide how you would like to handle lists, particularly since lists can contain elements of different types.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have to have a clear understanding of what datatypes you're dealing with.

```
a = ["hello","world"] -> list of str
b = "hello" -> str
c = ['1.0','0.0'] -> list of str
d = [0,1,2] -> list of int
e = 0.100
```

'type()' will tell you the type of a variable. string_name.isdigit() will tell you if a string contains something that can be interpreted as numeric. isinstance(var, type) will tell you if some input is of a particular type.

You have to clearly define what sort of input you're dealing with (for example, are lists allowed to contain data of different types? Are you allowing more complex data types, such as dicts?). At that point, you can use the functions above to write your easy_type() function.